# Swiftui presentationMode is dismissed when hierarchy is repainted

Tags: swiftui

I'm working on a edit product page that on it's root has the model as a State and passes it to the subpaged as bindings.

In the edit page, I have if statements that show either a chooser or a text, depending on if one attribute is set.

The problem is, if I update the model in one of the subpages, presentatonMode.dismiss() is called when the hierarchy is repainted.

Sample code:

```
struct A: View {
    @Binding var s: Bool

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: AA(s: self.$s)) {
            Text("A")
        }
    }
}

struct AA: View {
    @Binding var s: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(s.description)
            Button(action: {
                self.s.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("toggle")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct B: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("B")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var s: Bool = true

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                if s == true {
                   A(s: self.$s)
                } else {
                    B()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As seen here, in the AA subpage, I only want to update the state and display it, not to have dismiss called and get back to content view.

[image]

Comment: Wait... but `@State s` is in `ContentView` and toggling it you just remove `A` (and subview `AA`) from view hierarchy replacing it with `B`... All behaves as designed (plus animation introduced by `NavigationView`). If you would expect something different then code should be different.

Comment: you are right. I didn't see the whole picture :/ my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due the fact I was replacing the whole view hierarchy. My Bad